# Why does OkHttp treat the Date header the same as it treats the Last-Modified header when setting the If-Modified-Since header?

Tags: http, github, okhttp

I am using a Jenkins plugin that uses the OkHttp library for handling integration with Github API.

Github's /repos/:owner/:repo endpoint returns error 404 when the OkHttp tries to requesting the resource with a token that is not allowed to access the resource. When the token's scope is expanded to allow it to access the resource, OkHttp makes the request with an If-Modified-Since header. The header's value is set to the Date header's value from the 404's response. The response from this second request is HTTP 304. According to Github's support team, this behavior is the proper behavior, since the resource (the data behind the /repos/:owner/:repo endpoint) has not been modified since the first request was made. However, this means that the OkHttp client now uses the cached 404 response.

It seems like the Date header was intended for calculating freshness, not checking when a resource was last modified. [RFC 7232 section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.3) says that clients may use the Date header's value as the If-Modified-Since value, but I have not come across other literature on the web suggesting that this behavior is accepted. I do not see any reference to the Date header in [Mozilla's documentation on the If-Modified-Since header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since).

Wouldn't Postel's Law suggest that OkHttp should try not to misuse the Date header by using it as another source for the If-Modified-Since header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFCs are definitive on what behavior is appropriate. If the RFC says that a `Date` header can be used with `If-Modified-Since`, then it can be.

Consider persuading GitHub to invalidate caches when a scope is expanded. If a response was served on 2017-03-01, and a token’s scope was expanded on 2017-04-01, then the resource was effectively modified on 2017-04-01.

Your other option is to disable OkHttp’s cache. Like every cache it violates of Postel’s Law as a consequence of honoring the directives of buggy cache configuration.